# Import Error using WX python on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm having trouble importing wx python to use on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

I installed it following the instructions on the downloads page, using:

```
pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-20.04 wxPython
```

This looks to install correctly, but when I try to use it I end up with this:

```
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wx/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from wx.core import *
  File "/home/chris/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wx/core.py", line 12, in <module>
    from ._core import *
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: hb_ot_metrics_get_position
>>>
```

Has anyone seen and successfully solved this problem?